# Custom tiles do not show up on GoogleMap map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, tile

I set up a custom `UrlTileProvider` to render tiles in the `MapsActivity` as follows:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        if (mMap == null) {
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    private void setUpMap() {
        TileProvider tileProvider = new CustomTileProvider();
        TileOverlayOptions tileOverlayOptions = new TileOverlayOptions()
            .tileProvider(tileProvider);
        tileOverlayOptions.visible(true);
        tileOverlayOptions.zIndex(10000);
        TileOverlay tileOverlay = mMap.addTileOverlay(tileOverlayOptions);
    }
}
```

..

```
public class CustomTileProvider extends UrlTileProvider {

    private static final int TILE_WIDTH = 256;
    private static final int TILE_HEIGHT = 256;
    private static final int MIN_ZOOM = 12;
    private static final int MAX_ZOOM = 16;
    private static final String TILE_SERVER_URL = ...

    public CustomTileProvider() {
        this(TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT);
    }

    public CustomTileProvider(final int width, final int height) {
        super(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public URL getTileUrl(int x, int y, int zoom) {
        String tileServerUrl = String.format(TILE_SERVER_URL, zoom, x, y);

        if (!checkTileExists(x, y, zoom)) {
            return null;
        }

        try {
            return new URL(tileServerUrl);
        } catch (MalformedURLException exception) {
            throw new AssertionError(exception);
        }
    }

    private boolean checkTileExists(int x, int y, int zoom) {
        if ((zoom < MIN_ZOOM || zoom > MAX_ZOOM)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

This is basically the same which can be found in the [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/tileoverlay).

For some reason no tiles show up for the area provided by the server. The method `getTileUrl()` is never called.

Comment: You should return TileProvider.NO_TILE instead of null, if you do not want to provide a tile for some zoom level or x/y coordinates. If you are absolute sure, that the method is never called, that will of course not fix your problem.

Comment: The `abstract` class `UrlTileProvider` requires implementing `public abstract java.net.URL getTileUrl(int i, int i1, int i2);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that `String.format` throws an `IllegalFormatException` which is not show in the logs.

I recommend to surround it with a `try ... catch` block.

Further, url-encoded `%` in `TILE_SERVER_URL` interfered with the format placeholders in `String.format(TILE_SERVER_URL, zoom, x, y)`.